# Very simple CSS animation from left to right

Tags: css, animation

How can I use CSS animation to move an image (in this case a GIF) from left (outside the screen) to right (outside the screen)?

The only thing that is important to me is that you can choose the speed, the animation will always repeat AND you can define how long you want to wait before the next repetition.

NO EaseIn or EaseOut, just a normal animation.

I have done some research on this, but have not found a satisfying solution anywhere.

Comment: Nothing to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `delay` part of an animation is used only to determine when an element should begin the animation, it cannot be reused after each iteration of the animation (only the first time). Therefore, we'll need `JavaScript` to do what you're asking. Instead of the `delay` being included in the `CSS`, it will now be included in the `JavaScript`.

We trigger the animation to begin when the page first loads listening to the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

We listen for the animation ending using the `animationend` event. When this happens, we set the animation to `none` and then back to an empty string. This will essentially restart the animation.

The code for the `animationend` handler, as well as the code for the `DOMContentLoaded` handler, both occur within `setTimeout` calls, with the delay assigned to a variable.

```js
const img = document.querySelector(".my-img");
const delay = 2000; // ms=

const handleDOMReady = () => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    img.classList.add("on");
  }, delay);
}

const handleAnimationEnd = () => {
  img.style.animation = "none"
  
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    img.style.animation = "";
  }, delay)
}

img.addEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd);

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleDOMReady);
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.my-img {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.my-img.on {
  --speed: 2s;
  animation: move var(--speed) linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  to { 
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="my-img" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="cat">
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca5gwLpz/1/)

Comment: Good, but I think the OP wants it to start off-screen and to repeat infinitely. `img {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: move 2s infinite linear;
}`

Comment: @Moob I appreciate the feedback. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That works great! Thanks so far! The delays works fine as well, but just one time. I would like to have an infinity animation, but once the graphics goes off screen on the right side the animation should wait X seconds before starting again. It would be great to have 2 delays: One delay for when the animation starts the first time - and another delay, when the animation should start all over again (without the first delay). Is that possible?

Comment: @dajana I've updated my answer and this is now working. I tried keeping it as simple as possible, but there is no pure `CSS` way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Thank you so much, it looks great. But how can you define when the animation should be repeated regardless of the waiting time at the start?

Example: The page is called up, you wait for 5 seconds and then the animation starts. After the animation, you should always wait 30 seconds before the animation starts again. So there are two time specifications: "Wait until the first start of the animation (this is only relevant once)" and "Time until the animation starts again".

Comment: @dajana.s I think I've done more than enough to satisfy the original question. Perhaps accept this one and open a new question, being as specific as possible in the description.